# Call data change event to write error plugs during OPC DA Server shutdown event

Tags: c#, opc, opc-da

I have a peculiar problem. I have an OPC DA client which upon running is getting the plug values correctly in the data change event. When the server shuts down,  in the server shutdown event i need to call the data change event to write to few error plugs. I am unable to add these plugs to the subscription event because the server connection fails and i get an exception. I googled and did a lot of research but everywhere it is mentioned that we just call the disconnect method inside server shutdown and no plug value change detection can happen. I use OPC.Automation dll for my OPC DA operations. The code is in c#.

Comment: What is, in this context, "plug" or "error plug"?